# For what reasons script behavior related to DOM can change in particular browsers?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, dom, cross-browser

The code below works differently depending on browser. It seems to me that sometimes DOM is not fully loaded despite $(document).ready or similar checks

"else" is never reached in Firefox, but SOMETIMES reached in Chrome or Opera on page reload.

For me this means that part of the script related to Vue-generated content doesn't work. Sometimes on reload everything works fine without making any changes.

```
if($('.content-generated-by-Vue(v-if)').length){
               
                console.log('sometimes this');
            }
            else{
                console.log('sometimes this');
            }
```

The strange thing is it seems that it works fine if user is authenticated as admin in laravel.

That's a real Laravel project and at first the problematic functionallity was located at "general script" public/js/functions.js

Then I've tried to separate it to other script and make it defer but it didn't work.
Now the functionallity is moved to "mounted" hook of Vue instance. Still works like before.

Why this script behavior change on f5 in general?

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

*In my case there* was a method inside the "created" hook of a Vue instance that was calling an AJAX which was allowing the render function v-for to render the content which I was trying to access by JS.

**For general cases** I concluded that if something works "sometimes" then this "something" has an asynchronous background. (Look for an AJAX)